# How to switch between local and remote selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, gitlab-ci, remotewebdriver

How is it possible to create a switcher between local and remote selenium webdrivers? Maybe we can choose in yml file??
I faced now with a problem: if I run tests locally -  pipline on gitlab failed, if it's OK on gitlab - cannot run tests locally.
For local tests I install it every time:
`(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())`

For gitlab create like

`webdriver.Remote(... )`

But how to switch automatically?

[This is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnZUL.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yep. I mean this - I switch between remote and local driver to run test manually but want to automate this. I want Gitlab understand what driver option to use. Please, see at my edited post, a linked a screenshot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use a conditional `if` statement. You can determine if you're running in GitLab CI or not by the presence of the predefined `CI` environment variable

```
if os.environ.get('CI', False):
    print('Running in GitLab CI')
    # ... import chromdrivermanager if needed
    driver = webdriver.Remote(...)
else:
    print('Not running in GitLab CI')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
```